# Why DRF is skipping validation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a Validator like this: (Yes it's empty and raises Expception)

```
class AlphanumericValidator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, value):
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            'Value should contain only letters, numbers, - and _ characters.'
        )
```

And the serializer:

```
class CampaignSerializer(CreatorModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=32, validators=[
        AlphanumericValidator()
    ])
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Campaign.objects.all(),
                fields=['account', 'name'],
                message='A campaign with this name is already exists.',
            ),
        ]
```

My Payload:

```
id: 5
name: "aaq???asdas"
```

My View:

```
class CampaignDetailView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsOwner, )

    def get_object(self, request, campaign_pk):
        campaign = get_object_or_404(Campaign, pk=campaign_pk)
        self.check_object_permissions(request, campaign)
        return campaign

    def put(self, request, campaign_pk):
        campaign = self.get_object(request, campaign_pk)
        serializer = CampaignSerializer(
            campaign,
            data=request.data,
            context={
                'request': request,
            }
        )
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()

        return Response(
            serializer.data,
        )
```

Permission IsOwner:

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.profile.account == obj.account
```

Serializer is validating the name successfully.

Where is my mistake?

Edit: I forgot to add end of the CampaignDetailSerializer.put method. I added them.

Comment: Your put method in CampaignDetailView is exactly what you got ? If not please edit for full "put" method inspection.

Comment: @monio I added the rest of the method.

Answer (score 0):

My wildest guess, is the way you are using the custom validator is meant to be used along with `ModelViewSet`, to trigger these validators.

If you are doing something custom, try overriding the `validate` method on the `ModelSerializer`

like the following

```
# I guess that CreatorModelSerializer is a sub-class of ModelSerializer.
class CampaignSerializer(CreatorModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        # Do Validations
        if True:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'ABBBBALIIIZA'
            )
        # Otherwise return the attributes
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=Campaign.objects.all(),
                fields=['account', 'name'],
                message='A campaign with this name is already exists.',
            ),
        ]
```

The validation should work properly after this change.